# Creating abstraction with CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am not really sure it is the correct title, if not please feel free to change it. I am not a native english speaker, so I will try my best to explain with help of a pic :

[image]

Lets assume that, I have a plain HTML file. This file makes use of buttons and use some UI library (like Yahoo Pure). But instead of using classes by Pure, I use my own classes, lets call it `myButton` , which in tern use Pure CSS (or any other). But how ?

Here I am trying to create an layer of abstraction so that my css file can use some different UI libraries (be it bootstrap, pure or foundation) & the code still would work.

Without this solution, I would be doing like this (my initial code would be) :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yahoo-pure.com/pure-min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="pure-button" type="button">Some Button</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then if I have my change of heart and decide to use bootstrap :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://twitter-bootstrap.com/bootstrap.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="btn" type="button">Some Button</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

So I have to make two changes here, one is source css file (not a big problem) and class for button (a very big problem if the code is large). (Imagine the changes I have to make if I am making use of grids & other stuffs)

What if I am able to do something like this :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="my-magic-stylesheet.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="myButton" type="button">Some button</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

So, when I feel like switching from Bootstrap to Pure, I only make changes inside `my-magic-stylesheet.css` & it should still work. My HTML file refers to `my-magic-stylesheet.css` and `my-magic-stylesheet.css` could refer to any library I specify.

One solution that comes to my mind is, which is quite simple, I write a python script. First I make note of different classes and their respective UI library. Then I will write a CSS in which I will use generic class names like `myButton`. Then I will feed this css to my script with name of UI library as another input. The script will run through the css file & make changes accordingly. (like changing `myButton` to `btn` if another input to script is `bootstrap`)

But is there any better approach to this ? May be without using python script ? Or any solution that comes to your mind ? also I am new to CSS tools like LESS/SASS. Can I use them in anyway to solve my problem ?

Comment: you should put that stylesheet in last whom style you want in priority

Comment: maybe doing like: class='pure-button btn' ?

Comment: @Hushme - Nope, that would not solve my problem. I have to make changes in class names too

Comment: @gen - but what if I want to switch between many libraries ? If I keep specifying many class names, it would mess it all up. Thats why I want to use a generic class which can use any library.

Comment: Using something like LESS or SASS would make this much easier.

Comment: use Ctrl+H in Notepad++ :P

Comment: I agree I think less may make this a bit easier. So I recently am looking at ways to change my own architecture, but I tend to stick within one framework (bootstrap 3) -  with a custom file for media queries, overrides, etc.. - then in my bootstrap.less i point to my custom file - but leave bootstrap alone - except for changing this one variable file.

Comment: You cannot create abstractions in CSS. The body of the question seems to revolve around authoring techniques without a well-defined problem.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - can you tell me which part of the question is not clear ? I will try to edit it and redefine.

Answer (score 1):

Using **LESS**:

```
.myButton {
    .btn;
    .pure-button;
}
```

Here you still need to deal manually with many classnames but at least only once.

Answer (score 0):

Hm ... interesting question. I think that you missed one very important point. If you jump from a framework to framework, you are not changing only the names of the classes, but your html markup as well. So, even if you find a good solution for *btn* liked problem you may not find a problem for grids definition. I.e. bootstrap may require two new *div* tag wrappers and foundation maybe needs only one. So, I think that the best approach in your case is to modulize everything. I.e. create various number of components. Every component will have three (or whatever is the number of needed frameworks) templates. I mean in your case the html markup looks more important then the css itself. At the end what you will need to do is to import the framework's library at the top and use the right template. You will not have to deal with CSS classes overrides or something like that. It's a hell if you go there.